# Attempted relative import beyond top-level package with sys.path.append()

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path

I know that question probably has been answered a thousand times already but I don't understand why my following code does not work. I have this basic structure

```
/directory
   /folder1
      /sub1
         /sub2
            /file1.py
   /folder2
      /file2.py
```

Now I want to import a class from file 2 into file 1:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('...')
from ...folder2 import someClass
```

But this gives me a compiler error

> Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Why?

Comment: so what is your execution file path is it file1 or file2  or it is outside of directory folder a single app.py file to run proeject if it is in outside of directory then you cn do `from directory.folder1.file1 import class` you need to maintain the file structure

Comment: the code is in file1. I am not quite sure what the executrion file path is but i think its somewhere in folder 1.  
I dont know if it is important but I have django project that is in folder 1, while folder 2 is not part of it.

Comment: what i am saying is what is the top level project directory from where the project start, in that directory you have a python file which run the django server,  this running file should be in topmost directory and other module like folder1 and folder 2 should be in below base path of directory, keeping this structure in mind you can import the file/classes/modules with ease like from `from directory.folder1.file1 import class1`  . you can take this as refernce for project structue [cookiecutter django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)

Comment: ah yes, that would work. But what if I dont want to have folder 2 in folder 1. How would I solve my problem?

Comment: in directory __init__py file write `from .folder2 import file2` and in file2 just write `from directory import file2`